# d3 transition error

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I am probably making a rookie D3 mistake here, but I am trying to use D3 to make an animated change in an existing HTML element.

So let's say I have the following HTML

```
<div id="label">Hello</div>
```

And then I am trying to change this with animated D3 as follows:

```
d3.select("#label").transition().duration(1000).html("World");
```

I get the following error

```
"Object [object Array] has no method 'html'"
```

When I leave out the transition all works well:

```
d3.select("#label").html("world");
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't think you can transition the html content of an element. What behavior are you expecting the `html` transition to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to do something like fade out the "hello" and then fade in the "world", you can do something like:

```
var $label = d3.select("#label");
$label.transition().duration(1000).style('opacity', 0);
$label.transition().delay(1000).duration(1000).text("World").style('opacity', 1);
```

However, note that the `text` method is applied immediately at the beginning of the second transition and will only work for plain-text, not html.

Comment: Thanks. That works. But how come "html" doesn't work? It is part of the D3 API isnt it?

Comment: It is not part of the `transition` api. [https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions)